# How to show a specific sequence bounded in $H^{-1}(\Omega)^n$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, sobolev-spaces, duality-theorems

Let $\Omega\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be a bounded smooth domain and $\{p_m^*\}\subset L^2(\Omega)$ a sequence. I know that for every $m\in \mathbb{N}$ the element $v(p_m^*)\in H_0^1(\Omega)^n$ satisfies
$$((v(p_m^*),w)) = (f,w) + (p_m^*, \text{div }w) \quad \forall w\in H_0^1(\Omega)^n,$$
where $((u,v))= \sum_{1\leq i,j \leq n}(D_iu_j, D_iv_j)$.

I also know that the sequence $\{v(p_m^*)\}$ is bounded in $H_0^1(\Omega)^n$.

**QUESTION:** How to show that $\{\nabla p_m^*\}$ is bounded in $H^{-1}(\Omega)^n$, which is the dual of $H_0^1(\Omega)^n$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By definition, the weak gradient satisfies
$$
\int_\Omega \nabla p_m \cdot \phi dx = -\int_\Omega p_m \ div(\phi) dx
$$
for all $\phi\in C_c^\infty(\Omega)^n$. Using your equation, this is 
equivalent to
$$
\int_\Omega \nabla p_m \cdot \phi dx = (f,\phi) - (( \nu(p_m),\phi)).
$$
Hence it holds
$$
\left | \int_\Omega \nabla p_m \cdot \phi dx \right|
\le \|f\|_{H^{-1}} \|\phi\|_{H^1} + \|\nu(p_m)\|_{H^1})\|\phi\|_{H^1}.
$$
This shows that the functionals
$$
\phi \mapsto  \int_\Omega \nabla p_m \cdot \phi dx
$$
are functionals on $H^1_0(\Omega)$, and bounded in $H^{-1}$, 
which implies that the weak gradients of $p_m$ are bounded in $H^{-1}$.

Comment: One should note that your first equation actually implies $|\int_\Omega \nabla p_m \cdot \phi \, \mathrm{d}x| \le \|p_m\|_{L^2}\,\|\phi\|_{H^1}$. By density, this implies the desired estimate. There is no need to talk about $\nu(p_m)$ and $f$.

Comment: There was no boundedness assumption on $p_m$, only boundedness of $\nu(p_m)$ was given.